# Isolated models in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to isolate models in `ng-repeat` but this models must have access to same data.

Here is JS-fiddle to illustrate a problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/r50adyx4/

If you click on add button and switch between select options you can see, that only first select input is isolated. Other two are changing in each repeated model.

```
<div class="addCert" ng-click="allLicences.push(allLicences.length+1)">
        <p>Add certification +</p>
    </div>
<form ng-submit="processForm()">
    <ul ng-repeat="licence in allLicences">
        <select ng-model="models[licence]" ng-options="l.cntryName for l in data"></select>
         <select ng-model="models[licence].discipline" ng-options="d.name for d in models[licence].disciplines"></select>
         <select ng-model="models[licence].discipline.level" ng-options="lvl.levelName for lvl in models[licence].discipline.levels"></select>
    </ul>
```

I thought that targeting models in ng-repeat with `models[licence]` would make every occurance isolated.

So what is going on?
How can i isolate other two so they will be unique for every ng-repeat?

EDIT to make thing more clear:
If you add one or more models (certificates) and you select the same country (let's say Slovenia) for all those models other two selects must be independent for each model.

If that would work i could select Slovenia -> Alpine skiing -> U1 in the first one and Slovenia -> Telemark -> U5 in the second one.
I hope i am clear enough...

Comment: These models are not isolated, though you might think they are.  the first select is populated with the entire `l` object, and selecting it binds the `l` object to `models[license]`.  selecting the same `l` in another dropdown will bind **the same** `l` object to that `models[license]`.  changes to any `l` will be reflected in all others.  What you want to do will require you breaking your data structure up into multiple lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vhkkm2t/4/)

Each item in the repeat should refer to a separate object (data) so that any bindings are separated.

JS

```
$scope.add = function () {
    $scope.allLicences.push(angular.copy($scope.data));
}

$scope.allLicences = [];
$scope.add();
```

Markup

```
<div class="addCert" ng-click="add()">
    <p>Add certification +</p>
</div>
<form ng-submit="processForm()">
    <ul ng-repeat="licenceItem in allLicences">
        <select ng-model="licence" ng-options="l.cntryName for l in licenceItem"></select>
        <select ng-model="licence.discipline" ng-options="d.name for d in licence.disciplines"></select>
        <select ng-model="level" ng-options="lvl.levelName for lvl in licence.discipline.levels"></select>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <hr>{{ allLicences}}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Edit**:

I think this version is better because you aren't making copies of **data** - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bhgjL0L/2/)

JS

```
$scope.add = function () {
    $scope.allLicences.push({});
}
```

Markup

```
    <ul ng-repeat="item in allLicences track by $index">
        <select ng-model="allLicences[$index].licence" ng-options="l.cntryName for l in data"></select>
        <select ng-model="allLicences[$index].discipline" ng-options="d.name for d in allLicences[$index].licence.disciplines"></select>
        <select ng-model="allLicences[$index].level" ng-options="lvl.levelName for lvl in allLicences[$index].discipline.levels"></select>
    </ul>
```

Comment: It doesn't actually... If i add two or more modules, discipline and levels (second and third select) are shared between them. This is what i want to isolate.

Comment: @Leonajs So you're saying that when a module (certification) is added and I select Solvenia in the first one discipline and levels are shared between the two modules in my JSFiddle?

Comment: No when you select different discipline or level, for the same Country (Slovenia), they are shared among other models

Comment: I updated the question to make things more clear. I hope you understand my problem now.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do sth like that, but i was just pushing the data object into allLicences and angular repeater was throwing error about duplicates.... I think that angular.copy does the trick here.

Comment: @Leonajs I've done an edit to include what I think is a better answer.